# document.scrolltop value unchanged after scrolling page

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I've based positioning of a drop down menu above/below an element's proximity to window bottom (so it doesn't get cut off), as calculated from $(document).scrollTop().

This works great, unless the user happens to scroll the page and re-opens the menu. In that case, the scrollTop value is unchanged (and menu not positioned correctly) unless the page is manually refreshed. Force-refreshing the page is not really desirable.

How can I ensure the scrollTop value is updated each time it's called, rather than by page reloads?

Thanks!

OK, I "solved" this (got it working to my satisfaction), and I mistook the "Edit Summary" thingie as the place to explain how. Not. Apologies. See my comment below where I explain how, again.

Comment: can you show some code

Comment: `var scrolly = $(document).scrollTop();alert(scrolly);` -- unchanged by scrolling, unless page is refreshed

Comment: Thought it might be because I have jquery-nicescroll plugin, so I did a bare test with just jquery, and confirmed the issue.

Comment: My edit comment is not showing up so just in case, I'll repeat: I moved the global "var scrolly = $(document).scrollTop()" into the function, and now scrollTop is being updated each time the function is called (I've sometimes have this issue with globals).

Comment: If you solve your question, please post an answer; don't write 'solved' in the title.

Comment: Yeah, I added a 'reason for edit' comment, but for some reason it doesn't show up. Maybe it's meant to be a secret?